# Dynamic field title D7

Tags: 7, entities

Basically I want to be able to have a user be able to specify a title for a long text and summary field. Functionality being that you could have this with only one field:

day 1: doing something
this is what we did on day 1

day 2: doing something on day 2
this is what we did on day 2

Basically I want one field input for my content type creation form that correlates a title and the paragraph to go with it. I thought of a shoddy way to do it by creating a separate content type and bringing in the copy with a views block but I feel like there should be a much simpler way to allow a user to input a title to attach to a long text and summary field.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but this sounds like it could be a job for the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module.